# how to prevent overlapping in word2vec?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

As you know, the skip-gram model learns vector representations of elements based on long sequences of elements and the contexts of each. This model has most commonly been applied to natural language by concatenating giant collections of text. These documents of are often concatenated into a single very long line of text, with no distinction of when a new document begins and ends. This ends up not being much of an issue in NLP because the percentage of the model training instances involving overlapping documents is a small percentage of the total number of instances. In Education data, this overlap can be much higher because of shorter sequences and high numbers of users (formerly "documents" in NLP). This is also a problem in other behavioral datasets, not just education. The problem manifests itself when inspecting the learned vectors and finding that the model has determined that many of the students' first encountered elements are very similar to the students' very last encountered elements. This is a bi-product of the "wrapping" of lines in the input to gensim (instances spanning the end of one student's sequence and the beginning of another). How can I identify where in the code this overlapping occurs and prohibit this overlap from happening during training in gensim.

Answer (score 1):

In skip-gram, words will only be used to predict other words within the adjustable `window` parameter.

Further, no 'wrapping' is performed between individual texts (sentences) provided in the corpus – words are only included in windows for words in the same example. For example, given the following two-sentence corpus...

```
['cats', 'chase', 'mice']
['bats', 'eat', 'mosquitos']
```

...there are no windows that include both 'mice' and 'bats'.

So if in your training, words are having an undesired influence on each other because they are appearing in each others' nearby context windows, you can either reduce your `window` parameter, or split your texts into more examples on the boundaries across which windows should not reach.

(There's no overlap applied in the code, so no need to find/change that code.)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  What about such situation: For example, There are two sentences: ['promises', 'to','supercharge','the','process', 'of','discovery.'] and ['in','social','science,','tapping','millions','of','posts'].     The window-size is 2. So, when the center word becomes 'discovery' in the first sentence. The training pair is ['process', 'discovery.'], ['of','discovery.']  OR ['process', 'discovery.'], ['of','discovery.'] , ['discovery.', 'in'] , and 'social', 'discovery.']. The later is want am caring about.

Comment: With the two lists-of-tokens you've shown, gensim's Word2Vec in skip-gram mode will *not* train the pairs `['discovery.', 'in']` or `['social', 'discovery.']`. It doesn't combine/span separate text examples like that. (If you wanted those pairs trained, you'd have to concatenate the two lists together in your corpus.)

Comment: So, you mean the gensim's Word2Vec in skip-gram mode will just discard the word pairs (**['discovery.', 'in']** and **['social', 'discovery.']**), only train on **['process', 'discovery.']** and **['of','discovery.']**. But in this way, some information will  lost, both at the very beginning of a sentence and at the end of a sentence(shown above).

Comment: It doesn't discard them; it never creates them. Each text (list-of-tokens) you provide is handled separately. It loops over each word in that text, then each word within that word's window in that text, to create the skip-gram training pairs. If a word is near the edges, the window is truncated to the edge of the text. When it's done with one text, it moves on to the next – with no fragments of the prior text attached in any way to the next text. The original word2vec.c code on which the gensim implementation was based works the same way.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much! The last question is: Could you please give me some posts or links that you think may be helpful to understand the source code better.

Comment: I don't know of any resources which further explain the source code. It is its own best, most-authoritative explanation. Perhaps by looking at both the original word2vec.c, and the gensim word2vec.py, you can get a better idea of what any tricky parts are doing.